# Creating a Repository Query that include TextCriteria AND one other field

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

My Database Document looks like this

```
@Document(collection = "campaign")
class Campaign {

    @Id
    var id: String? = null
    @Indexed
    @TextIndexed(weight = 1f)
    var name: String? = null
    var mediaLink: String? = null
    var imageLink: String? = null
    @TextIndexed(weight = 2f)
    var text: String? = null
    @TextIndexed(weight = 2f)
    var target: String? = null
    var ownerId: String? = null     // Who can modify this except "MANAGER"
    var useScope: String? = null    // Who can Use this Campaign [me, dl, all] i.e. Visibility
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    var startOn: Date? = null       // @ this date the campaign becomes available and usable
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    var expireOn: Date? = null      // @ this date the campaign becomes expired and not usable
    var timestamp: Date? = null
    ....
```

The Repository

```
@Repository
interface CampaignRepository : MongoRepository<Campaign, String> {

    // page through results for full text query
    fun findAllBy(textCriteria: TextCriteria?, pageable: Pageable): Page<Campaign?>?
```

This actually produces a nice and complete search over the fields annotated with `@TextIndexed`
The problem is that the moment I add another filter field like I want to filter on `ownerId`
the whole query either don't compile or change the `TextCriteria` to `String` in the repository function.
Business logic requires me ONLY to show the data for the Owner

I have tried

```
// Expected parameter types: String , String not String, TextCriteria
fun findAllByOwnerId(ownerId: String?, textCriteria: TextCriteria?, pageable: Pageable): Page<Campaign?>?
// Property name must not be null or empty: 'findAllBy<EMPTY_PROPERTY>AndOwnerId'
un findAllByAndOwnerId(ownerId: String, textCriteria: TextCriteria?, pageable: Pageable): Page<Campaign?>?
// No property findAllOwnerId found for type Campaign! during Compiletime
fun findAllOwnerId(ownerId: String, textCriteria: TextCriteria?, pageable: Pageable): Page<Campaign?>?
```

Me GiveUp!  Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Java, you can use `@Query` annotation in the repository and pass the fields which requires in where clauses, as in the official documenation of spring-data-mongodb

**6.3.2. Mongo JSON based query methods and field restriction**: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/

> By adding the annotation org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query repository finder methods you can specify a Mongo JSON query string to use instead of having the query derived from the method name.

**For Text search with extra and parameters in `and` clause, including pageable parameters**

```
@Query("{$and:[ {'ownerId': ?0} , {'$text' : { '$search' : ?1}} ]}")
Page<Campaign> searchByByOwnerIdAndText(String ownerId, String keywords,
Pageable page);
```

Debug log of the above query is:

```
2019-12-29 14:03:42.053 DEBUG 10998 --- [           main] o.s.d.m.r.query.StringBasedMongoQuery    : Created query Document{{$and=[Document{{ownerId=12}}, Document{{$text=Document{{$search=Krishna}}}}]}} for Document{{}} fields.
```

For details about the above code, you can visit by Github page: https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/blob/master/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb/src/main/java/sample/data/mongo/repository/CampaignRepository.java#L11

Hope this will help you in your Kotlin code as well.

Comment: Thanx a Lot
I thought of doing this BUT to do It via QueryDSl (Whitch have its own implementation problems currently with Gradle 5+) because you can use code completion in IDE
IDE refactoring tools work (more-or-less)
type-safe
(almost) syntax-safe
compiler generates errors on compile time of wrong types etc vs runtime Excdeptions
**BUT this will do for now THANX**